# Spark Controller installation fails via ambari

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, failed-installation

When we are trying to install Spark Controller via Ambari, it is giving error.

below is the error we are getting:

stderr: `/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/errors-403.txt`

> File
>   "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.3/services/SparkController/package/scripts/controller_conf.py",
>   line 10, in controller_conf recursive = True
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py",
>   line 147, in **init** raise Fail("%s received unsupported argument %s"
>   % (self, key)) resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail:
>   Directory['/usr/sap/spark/controller/conf'] received unsupported
>   argument recursive

stdout: `/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/output-403.txt`

```
2016-12-15 08:44:36,441 - Skipping installation of existing package curl
2016-12-15 08:44:36,441 - Package['hdp-select']   {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5} 
2016-12-15 08:44:36,496 - Skipping installation of existing package hdp-select Start installing 
2016-12-15 08:44:36,668 - Execute['cp -r /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.3/services/SparkController/package/files/sap/spark /usr/sap'] {} 
2016-12-15 08:44:36,685 - Execute['chown hanaes:sapsys /var/log/hanaes'] {} Configuring... Command failed after 1 tries
```

Versions:

```
Ambari : 2.4.2.0   
Spark : 1.5.2.2.3   
Spark Controller : 1.6.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Raised Customer message towards SAP and the resolution was: "Known issue for Spark Controller 1.6.2, so please updagrade to Spark Controller 2.0".

After upgrading to Spark Controller 2.0 the installation was successful. Hence closing this thread.